# Synchronize datatable/dataview for read write

Tags: .net, datatable, dataview, readerwriterlock

I have application in .net 2.0 in which I have a DataTable object globally in my application and have different dataviews in whole application.

When an action performed i have create many threads lets say 5 in which data is read from different dataview, meanwhile while 2/3 threads are reading data(not all 2 more left to read data) a thread write data in datatable. So we get exceptions like "Enumeration update" or "parameter not null" type.

I have use ReadWriteLock for this but do not find any luck it gets stop on ReaderWriterLock.AcquireWriterLock().

I do not understand where i am doing wrong.

If anyone have any idea. Please help me how to implement ReaderWriterLock for this scenario for datatable and dataview.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163599.aspx) might be of some help. The library that Jeffrey Richter talks about is available [here](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx).

Since the application is being developed in .Net 2.0, I recommend going for a custom ReaderWriterLock which prefers writers over readers. Also, if you are looking for some source code, then [this guy](http://tdanecker.blogspot.com/2007/08/faster-and-more-reliable.html) might be of your help. One of the custom ReaderWriterLock, he wrote:

```
public sealed class ReaderWriterLock
{
    int readers = 0;
    int writers = 0;

    public void AcquireReaderLock()
    {
        Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();

        while (true)
        {
            if (Thread.VolatileRead(ref writers) == 0)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref readers);

                if (Thread.VolatileRead(ref writers) == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref readers);
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    public void ReleaseReaderLock()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref readers);

        Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
    }
    public void AcquireWriterLock()
    {
        Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();

        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref writers, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        while (Thread.VolatileRead(ref readers) != 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    public void ReleaseWriterLock()
    {
        Thread.VolatileWrite(ref writers, 0);

        Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
    }
}
```

Key points:

1. Prefers writers over readers
2. First come first serve
3. Spin lock used so ideal for SHORT lock-durations only